# Windows Phone: How to set the Value of TimeSpanPicker Programmatically?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am trying to use TimeSpanPicker in my application. How Can I set the value to "00:00:00"? For example, I am creating an instance and setting the  Value to "00:00:00" but it seems that
I should not assign a String ("00:00:00") to ts.Value.

```
enter code here
  TimeSpanPicker ts= new TimeSpanPicker();
  ts.Value="00:00:00";
```

**Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.TimeSpan?**

How can I set TimeSpanPicker's value?

Thanks,
Bahador

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a close look at the error you are getting, it says that it can not automatically convert a string to a TimeSpan and that the Value is expecting a TimeSpan. If you further look at your TimeSpan Object you will find that it has a Parse Method. So something like this will work for you.

```
TimeSpanPicker ts= new TimeSpanPicker();
ts.Value= TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:00");
```